# Perl and MongoDB update issue

Tags: perl, mongodb

i tried to use https://metacpan.org/release/MongoDB module over perl and found a small bug or i haven't enough material on doc

this is where i got error

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f625c0fcd4481bc13000000"), "mode" : "running", "res" : "running", "custid":NumberLong(155655062)}

db.movie.update({custid:NumberLong(155655062)},{'$set':{mode:"testing"}});
```

I am able to update the thing here but not able to update from perl code.

```
my $res = $db->movie->update({'custid'=>'NumberLong(155655062)'},{'$set' => { 'mode' => 'testing' }});
```

did i miss any code in the above example

Comment: you're using NumberLong which is a shell type that doesn't exist in Perl.

Comment: Barrie so how could i get access to NumberLong in perl .. is there any alternative to it

Comment: schwern i am not able to select the numberlong from normal traditional method

Comment: As Nat suggested in the google groups, "Instead of using NumberLong, use bigint on 32bit platform or simply use number directly on 64-bit platform.
http://search.cpan.org/~kristina/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/DataTypes.pod"

Comment: @Barrie i figured it out thanks for tip

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cust_id = 155655062; OR my $cust_id = int($record->{custid});
my $res = $db->movie->update({'custid'=>$cust_id},{'$set' => { 'mode' => 'testing' }});
```

Try this, it should work.